# Function Matching Error in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Why is The following code is giving me the following compiler-error: "Cannot find a match for eat()"?

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

void spit(char in[255])
{
    cout << in;
}

void spit (int in)
{
    cout << in;
}

int eat(int in)
{
    cout << "? ";
    cin >> in;
    return in;
}

char*  eat(char in[255])
{
    cout << "? ";
    cin >> in;
    return in;
}

int main()
{
clrscr();

int input;
input = eat(); // <---- over here
spit(input);

getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You aren't passing a parameter when you call `eat`.

Comment: Great. What is your question? I don't see a question anywhere in your post.

Comment: Edited! sorry was in a hurry this time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a parameter to eat

```
..
int input;
input = eat(123);
spit(input);
..
```

But why do have function eat/spit with `char [255]` as parameters?
You don't use it

Comment: i am trying to create a library since I will be using them a lot

Comment: Yeah, wanna eat - bring something to eat.

Answer (score 1):

Your `eat` function requires an argument.

Answer (score 1):

you have two `eat()` overloads. Both of them require a parameter. You should specify a parameter when calling it either `int` or `char*` depending on you need. Or create a new `eat()` function that takes no params.